# Storing web service response

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, logging, reporting

I have a web service (in java) that selects an option out of two possibilities based on the data received in the request.

I want to be able to store the incoming data and the corresponding action that was taken, in a file (preferably HTML) which can be viewed later.

This sounds a lot like logging and I tried that but the problem I am facing is displaying the data in a format I want.

Loggers typically print the data in different rows. I wanted to have the data in different columns - something like - |Request param1 | Request param2 | Action Taken |

If I do something like -

```
LOGGER.log(Request param1);
LOGGER.log(Request param2);
LOGGER.log(Action Taken);
```

[I know this is not syntactically correct, its just to convey the idea]

These come in separate rows. If I do something like -

```
LOGGER.log(Request param1 + Request param2 + Action Taken);
```

it comes in a single column.

How to get it in different columns? Or is there any other alternative to achieve what I want? I also looked into Jasper Reports but that might be too complex to use for this.

Please help. Forgive me if I am not concise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as it is logically one message, doesn't matter the rendering columns or not. You are on a right way. Just possible improvement is to create some utility class for formatting.

Also, there are MDC and NDC approaches, which can give you colummn like formatting, but are wrong for one message and are really powerful thing for context based messages.
F.e. log4j implementation https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html